# New API project has yellow exclamation marks on Dependencies > Analyzers

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

Just created a new ASP.NET Core Application using Visual Studio 2019 16.4.4 and it's having yellow exclamation marks under Dependencies > Analyzers. The API runs and returns data. Any way to resolve this?

Running `dotnet restore` in package manager console, and restarting VS did not make any difference.

[image]

[image: Yellow Exclamation Marks VS]